# Getting started with multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I'm trying to set up a multiprocess in my script: I want to loop through an array and run a function for every item in the array but I want this function to be called simultaneously.

This is the original set up:

```
def my_function(my_variable):
    #DO stuff
    return my_variable_updated

def main():
    #initialize my_variable as a list with 10000 items
    results = []
    for item in my_variable:
    results.append(my_function(item))

    #continue script
```

How can I convert this to multiprocessing so I can run multiple `my_functions` at the same time and get to '#continue script' faster? Do I need to use a `queue` for this?

Comment: Create a `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` object (using default values for constructor is ok here) and use its `map` method.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to restructure your script pretty thoroughly to implement `multiprocessing`. The main script would look something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, JoinableQueue, Manager

def my_function(input_queue, manager_list):
    while True:
        item_to_process = input_queue.get() # item_to_process will be an (index, item) tuple
        result_of_processing = item_to_process[1] ** 2
        manager_list[item_to_process[0]] = result_of_processing
        input_queue.task_done()

def main():
    item_count = 10 # 10000 in your case
    my_variable = [i for i in range(item_count)]
    q = JoinableQueue()
    for index, item in enumerate(my_variable):
        q.put((index, item))
    manager = Manager()
    results = manager.list([0] * item_count) # initialize to same size as my_variable
    worker_count = 2
    for _ in range(worker_count):
        p = Process(target=my_function, args=[q, results])
        p.daemon = True # optional, but should be used unless your subprocess will spawn another process
        p.start()
    # now you can continue on
    # but when you need to access `results` you have to put:
    q.join()
    # now we have our results
    print(results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Yeilding

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

In my simple case.

You can also use a pool, but I'm not well versed in that and wouldn't want to lead you astray.

The main thing to watch out for when using multiprocessing is avoiding deadlocks, and also maintaining shared memory, and it can get tricky fast! In most cases it would be sufficient and recommended to use `threading.Thread` instead! This module is super easy to get cooking away with, but you will still likely need a `queue.Queue`. However, you wouldn't have to worry about sharing memory and things like `multiprocessing.Manager`'s

Comment: In my case,  the items to process are lists with 5 elements. I tried this, but it didn't work: item_to_process = input_queue.get()....new_item = item_to_process[0]....then do stuff with new_item[0]...new_item[1]...new_item[4]...what' wrong with this?